# Django DRY functions in forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

In my **forms.py** I have to setup and then clean a lot of similar variables.

```
class FormOne(forms.Form):
    email_field = forms.EmailField(
        required=True,
        max_length=70,
        label=mark_safe("""<i>Enter email address</i>"""))

    # other fields

    def clean_email_field(self):
        return data

class FormTwo(forms.Form):
    email_field = forms.EmailField(
        required=True,
        max_length=70,
        label=mark_safe("""<i>Enter email address</i>"""))

    # other fields

    def clean_email_field(self):
        return data
```

In my **views.py** I can successfully define a function at the bottom of the file and reference it in the code above. But if I try to put something like this at the bottom of the file:

```
def clean_email_field(form_data):
    # rest of function
```

then I get the error:

```
***ERROR*** clean_email_field undefined
```

Is it because forms are classes, not defs?

Comment: Try putting that above the form classes where its being referenced

Comment: @Umair if I put it inside `def my_func(): my_var = something return my_var` and then call my_func() within a form class it does not include the output of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include additional validation to your email field, then you could maybe write a [custom validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/validators/#writing-validators) and then include it in your [form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#validators). For example:

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_contains_something(value):
    if 'something' not in value:
        raise ValidationError('no 'something' found')

class FormTwo(forms.Form):
    email_field = forms.EmailField(
        required=True,
        max_length=70,
        label=mark_safe("""<i>Enter email address</i>"""),
        validators=[
            validate_contains_something,
        ])
```

You could even write your custom field with your custom validators as the default (as seen in [this example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#using-validators)):

```
class CustomEmailField(forms.EmailField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(
            *args,
            required=True,
            max_length=70,
            label=mark_safe("""<i>Enter email address</i>"""),
            validators=[
                validate_contains_something,
            ],
            **kwargs)

class CustomEmailField2(forms.EmailField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('required', True)
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 70)
        kwargs.setdefault('label', mark_safe("""<i>Enter email address</i>"""))
        kwargs.setdefault('validators', [validate_contains_something, ])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This approach could be an easier way to write your validation logic only once.

Comment: @Raif trying to figure out how to format `validators = [ ]` based on http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/

Comment: for `required= False, initial=True, label =`

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I don't understand exactly what you want. Do you need to include `required`, `initial` and `label` in all the field as well? I edited my question to include that.

Comment: thanks man! I think this post is really valuable for the community. 
`148 deletions(-)`